# How do I restore parent folder of modules in Idea

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I created a java Idea project in a directory, say /path/X/Z, so my project tab looked like this:

```
Z
-.idea
project.iml
```

I then added a few maven modules, say A, B to the project, so my project tab looked like this:

```
Z
---------A
---------A.iml
---------pom.xml
---------B
---------B.iml
---------pom.xml
-.idea
project.iml
```

with this structure, i could right-click onto Z and get Git operations for every module (the whole project was under one Git root).

I then renamed the parent directory of Z, X, to something else, say Y, outside of idea, and then reopened idea picking directory /path/Y/Z.

I had to reimport all modules, but now my project pane looks like this:

```
A
A.iml
pom.xml
B
B.iml
pom.xml
```

and the root directory Z was not there, meaning, only the modules are showing. I now have to right-click on every module to do Git operations.

How do I restore the root directory Z in the Project pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Z
    +-.idea
    +project.iml
    +pom.xml
A
     +A.iml
     +pom.xml

B
     +B.iml
     +pom.xml   


>pom.xml(Z) <-- parent

..
<modules>
        <module>../A</module>
        <module>../B</module>
</modules>
..

>pom.xml(A) <-- child1

<parent>
        <groupId>ma.****</groupId>
        <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
        <version>**</version>
        <relativePath>../Z</relativePath>
</parent>

>pom.xml(B) <-- child2

<parent>
        <groupId>ma.****</groupId>
        <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
        <version>**</version>
        <relativePath>../Z</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: let me see if i got you right: modify parent pom to include child poms, and then reimport project in idea?

Comment: parent not include child but declare its at modules